# How would I mock `request.xhr?` in a Rails 5 helper spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm testing Rails 5 helpers in rspec. We have a block in a helper which is wrapped in a conditional:

```
if request.xhr?
  # do stuff
end
```

In the specs, I'm unable to force that `request.xhr?` test to return true. I've tried `allow_any_instance_of(ActionController::Request).to receive(:xhr?).and_return(true)` but that says `Undefined Constant ActionController::Request` (which sort of makes sense). I also tried `allow(request).to receive(:xhr?).and_return(true)` but that just failed silently.

How can I test this - both that the `#do stuff` code is executed when we want it to be, and that it does what we expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be `allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:xhr?).and_return(true)`. I had missed that the Request object had moved out of the ActionController module and into ActionDispatch.